# mysql performance union of multiple count with different condition

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table contains 1.5 million records, and need to show several amount with different condition on the web page.

Assume table construction like this:

```
+-------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| userId| int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| cona  | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| conb  | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| conc  | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| date  | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

need to query user amount with different condition like this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT userId) FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DISTINCT userId) FROM test WHERE cona=0
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DISTINCT userId) FROM test WHERE cona=1
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DISTINCT userId) FROM test WHERE conb=0
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DISTINCT userId) FROM test WHERE conb=1 AND conc=0
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DISTINCT userId) FROM test WHERE conb=1 AND conc>0 AND date IS NOT NULL AND NOW() > date
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DISTINCT userId) FROM test WHERE conb=1 AND conc=1 AND date IS NOT NULL AND NOW() <= date
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DISTINCT userId) FROM test WHERE conb=1 AND conc=2 AND date IS NOT NULL AND NOW() <= date
UNION ALL
SELECT count(DISTINCT userId) FROM test WHERE conb=2
```

Every count query cost around 300~500ms, but union all the count query make this sql cost around 8~9s.

I tried add index on `userId, cona, conb, conc`

```
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD INDEX( `userId`);
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD INDEX( `cona`);
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD INDEX( `conb`);
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD INDEX( `conc`);
```

But the cost is same as before.
I really have no experience on sql optimization.
Is it possible to optimization the union sql?

Comment: Try to use temporary table and then insert all data in the temp table first, then you can now manipulate the temporary table and apply all your conditions.

Comment: Do you use something to communicate to MySQL?